# Total Commander using Windows copy mechanism insteand of it's own

Tags: windows-10, total-commander

When I want to copy something with Total Commander on mobile device, this is the windows that appears

[image]

however, this is the (as I understand it) windows explorer handling the the copy process.

What I want, is Total commander handling the copy, like on this image (not My image, found it online, but from paths shown it implies local system copy/paste:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I even tried different distribution from my collegue, his copy paste works just as expected, however on my pc, it just defaults to Windows copy mechanism. Where can I change this?

EDIT:1

It is true that I've been copying the files to a phone in the first image. To test copy on local fileSystem, new image was generated:

[image]

So, even on local filesystem, total commander doesn't seem to use it's own implementation.

Also to clear thing out, I'm running Windows 10 64 bit Enterprise edition

Comment: For local copies, 1) do you use F5/F6 or do you drag&drop? 2) does TotalCmd request administrator permission for the copy?

Comment: is there a reason you prefer Total Commander's copy feature instead of Windows'? Both have the ability to pause and rename on duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot doesn't look like the regular Windows Explorer file copy dialog. Instead, it looks like the Windows *PTP/MTP shell extension* file copy dialog.

You're copying to a phone or another device which doesn't allow direct filesystem-level access – it only provides MTP protocol access, and MTP on Windows is handled by Explorer as a "virtual" folder that doesn't correspond to any filesystem location. It has no (and cannot have) a drive letter or a mountpoint, and the paths seen are only valid within Explorer itself, not OS-wide.

(Even if you use an MTP addon to browse the items directly in TotalCmd, it does not change the situation, it just puts the MTP client inside a different program.)

As a result, Total Commander cannot use its regular file-based copy because there's nowhere to copy those files to.

---

Re edit: For real file-based copies, the only thing that comes to mind is whether you haven't accidentally *selected* the "Explorer" method in TotalCmd's preferences screen:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, the question was lacking in detail. Yes, I was copying file to a phone so I did a quick test and different dialog window was shown, however it is still not quite what I want. I Updated my question with the results of my new test. 

also thank you for explaining the mechanics of copying to a device, I was not aware of this.